# How to import library URLEncodedUtils in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils in android studio. It have to add library in build gradle I add this code

```
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6'
```

It show error like this.

> httpclient defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by
>   Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative
>   libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for
>   httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging
>   the library using something like jarjar.

If I remove implementation in build gradle it show error can not resolv symbol URLEncodedUtils. 
How to import library URLEncodedUtils android studio ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6'
and add this to your gradle:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

You also may try to download and include HttpClient jar directly into your project or use OkHttp instead. 
Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Add next block to `build.gradle` located in app module

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
}
```